# When hadoop-env.sh will be executed in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, configuration-files, hadoop2

I have moved hadoop-env.sh file from default location to /etc/hadoop location. I am not sure if I need to place an entry in ~/.bashrc file to execute this file. Can you please let me know if I need to place an entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hadoop-env.sh is called in hadoop-daemon.sh(start-all.sh-->start-dfs.sh-->hadoop-daemon.sh). Below is the snippet.

```
if [ -f "${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/hadoop-env.sh" ]; then
. "${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/hadoop-env.sh"
fi
```

You would have to set your JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.sh along with other environmental variables required. So it has to be called/executed before all your demons start. With that said if you are moving that out from HADOOP_CONF_DIR(defaults to HADOOP_HOME/conf) then you have to call that in your bashrc.sh or embed your path in hadoo-daemon.sh to call your hadoop-env.sh in above snippet.